# 'd instead of would - when is it acceptable?

Tags: conditionals, would

I am a teacher of English as a second language (secondary school). I've been correcting a test on the 3rd conditional - the task was to change the given sentences from a 2nd conditional form to a 3rd conditional one - and many students wrote the following:
1) The manager'd pay high salaries if more profits were made.

I want to point out to them that they should have written the complete form "The manager would pay high salaries ... " instead of the abbreviation "'d", but I don't know how to explain the grammatical reason why. I just know (or feel) it's wrong, but I need to provide an adequate explanation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46837/discussion-on-question-by-g-los-d-instead-of-would-when-is-it-acceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that the students should be encouraged not to use the contraction in this sentence.

The reason I would give is that people would have trouble understanding them if they used a contraction here.

Contractions of *would* are clearly understandable with the pronouns (e.g. *he'd, she'd we'd,* etc., but with less common uses, the listener would have to work too hard to understand.  If you try speaking this sentence out loud, you'll see what I mean.  *Manager'd* sounds like *manager* is a verb and we put it in the past tense.  Which doesn't make sense in this context -- so then the listener has to play it back in his mind and re-parse it.  Rule #1 in communicating in a non-native language: make it easy for your listener to understand you.

(Such a contraction would only be used in written English if one were writing dialogue or writing something that evokes spoken English.)

Comment: People use a contracted *would* in speech, but it's usually pronounced /əd/ and not /d/. So manager'd would be pronounced /mæneɪdʒərəd/ and not /mæneɪdʒərd/. [See dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would).

Comment: @PeterShor - Pardon me for asking this, but have you actually had the experience of struggling to make yourself understood in a non-English-speaking country?  It is this practical experience which gave birth to my Rule #1.